# angularjs service doesn't work fine when call for API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was working with a angular project that include controllers and services. problem comes out from the codes following:

qrcodeCtrl.js

```
angular
.module('Admin',['ngResource'])
.controller('qrcodeCtrl',function($scope,qrcodeservice,statusservice){
            $scope.init = function(){
                $scope.getQrcodes();
            }
            $scope.getQrcodes = function(){
                qrcodeservice.getQrcodes()
                .then(function(res){
                    $scope.qrcodes = qrcodeservice.qrcodeList;
                    $scope.loginstatus = [];
                    var logininfo = [];    
                    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.qrcodes.length; i++){
                        logininfo[i] = self.setInterval(getloginfo,10000,i);
                    }
                    function getloginfo(i){
                        uuid = $scope.qrcodes[i];
                        statusservice.getstatus(uuid).then(function (result) {
                            console.log(uuid+"   "+result.code);
                            uuid = result.uuid;   
                            switch(result.code){
                                case 201 : $scope.loginstatus[uuid] = 'login ...';break;
                                case 200 : $scope.loginstatus[uuid] = 'login success';window.clearInterval(logininfo[i]);break;
                                case 500 : $scope.loginstatus[uuid] = 'login fail';window.clearInterval(logininfo[i]);break;
                                default : $scope.loginstatus[uuid] = 'waitting';break;       //code  408
                            }
                        },function (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        })
                        return;
                    }
                },function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }
            $scope.init();
        })
```

statuservice.js

```
angular
.module('Admin',['ngResource'])
.service('statusservice',function ($http,$q) {
            var auth = this;
            auth.getstatus = function(uuid){
                var defer = $q.defer();
                // //debug
                // var code = 200;
                // var result = {"uuid":uuid,"code":code};
                // defer.resolve(result);
                // return defer.promise;
                // //=================
                $http.get("/check?uuid="+uuid)
                    .success(function(code){
                        res = {"uuid":uuid,"code":code};
                        defer.resolve(res);
                    })
                    .error(function(err,status){
                        console.log(err);
                        defer.reject(err);
                    })
                return defer.promise;
            }
        })
```

about the codes, the service is for getting login info from API which test work fine.  and the controller set a interval for getting login info from service constantly. When it turn out login success(200) or login fail (500), the interval will stop. those codes work for login section of a project.

When service doesn't get the login code from API and just write the code, (comment section)the service work fine , the code is 200 and  the interval stop, alse view render fine.

But when service get the login code from API, the interval doesn't stop.  and from the chrome console , i find out that the code is success change to 200, but still loop the interval.  and the view doesn't render to login success.

I was learning angular for few days, could someone tell me why that happen??

Comment: What is the `self` property? Why has it `php` extension? Why don't you use angular's `$interval` service?

Comment: sorry, the php extension was my fault when coding question.  and the use of  `self` is the result of my searching from Internate,   i find out that it will work both `self.setInterval()` or `window.setInterval()`, also just `setInterval()` still working. Finnaly,  cause you mention the `$interval` service, I will try it out now.

Answer (score 0):

your module declaration and usage is incorrect

```
 angular.module('Admin',['ngResource']).something should not be done;
```

this initialize module admin every time.

you should declare in the below format

```
var app = angular.module('Admin',['ngResource']);

angular
.module('Admin')
.service('statusservice',function ($http,$q) {
});

angular
.module('Admin')
.controller('qrcodeCtrl',function($scope,qrcodeservice,statusservice){
 });
```